# How to Persist Mobx State Tree in React Native?

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I need to persist a MST Store in React Native. The data is changed seldomly.

I'm confused between using AsyncStorage and AutoRun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For persisting MST stores, you might be interested in using [`mst-persist`](https://github.com/agilgur5/mst-persist), which, per the README, is currently a small wrapper around MST's `onSnapshot` and `applySnapshot` (disclaimer: I'm the creator).

To persist data in React Native with `mst-persist` backed by `AsyncStorage`, one would do:

```js
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import { persist } from 'mst-persist'

const SomeStore = types.model('Store', {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 32
})

const someStore = SomeStore.create()

persist('some', someStore, {
  storage: AsyncStorage,  // default: localStorage
  jsonify: true  // if you use AsyncStorage, this should be true
                  // default: true
  whitelist: ['name']  // only these keys will be persisted
}).then(() => console.log('someStore has been hydrated'))
```

My original use case for `mst-persist` was for React Native and the current README will actually point you to [a commit](https://github.com/agilgur5/react-native-manga-reader-app/pull/2/commits/286725f417d321f25d16ee3858b0e7e6b7886e77) in an OSS RN manga reader app I made as an example.

If you're interested in how to do it with MST without another library like `mst-persist`, the persistence source code is actually < 50 LoC currently. And minus some features, it's a brisk < 20 LoC:

```js
import { onSnapshot, applySnapshot } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export const persist = (name, store, options = {}) => {
  let {storage, jsonify} = options

  onSnapshot(store, (_snapshot) => {
    const snapshot = { ..._snapshot }
    const data = !jsonify ? snapshot : JSON.stringify(snapshot)
    storage.setItem(name, data)
  })

  return storage.getItem(name)
    .then((data) => {
      const snapshot = !jsonify ? data : JSON.parse(data)
      applySnapshot(store, snapshot)
    })
}
```

There are a handful of other examples out in the wild that show similar functionality as well, such as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benjick/c48dd2db575e79c7b0b1043de4556ebc) that `mst-persist` is partly inspired by, [this repo](https://github.com/tallpants/mobx-state-tree-persist-example) that uses HoCs and `PersistGate`s similar to `redux-persist`, and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/terrysahaidak/43f316d278f8519538e69e7fd2c737a3) that takes multiple stores as an argument.